# Android, Bluetooth, catching special commands from BT device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

How can we listen for special BT device commands like redial from our app? For now, I'm only able to listen to the only one - play/pause/start/end call button (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE).
Using common BroadcastReceiver for "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" doesn't help.
Solution with BluetoothSocket, BluetoothServerSocket won't help too since it requires our code to be invoked on BT device side.
During my redial button tests I see the next line in the logs:

> 01-20 05:52:30.486 942-1060/com.android.bluetooth E/bt-rfcomm: PORT_DataInd, p_port:0x5526c200, p_data_co_callback is null

It looks like there is something sending an event from BT device to the android device. But how can we catch it on app side, what should we use? I work on some system app by the way and theoretically can do very specific, low-level and system things, so maybe there could be some solution.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, this isn't possible, sadly...

I've been working on custom handling BT headset keys, like VOL UP, DOWN, eventually ANSWER/DISCONNECT/REDIAL. Even made rich [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569033/handling-bluetooth-headset-keys), but without single answer or comment...

After some research (days, weeks...) and digging into Android source I've found that these buttons are sending some AT commands. I've also found methods which are checking these AT commands and if system is able to respond/handle them then it TRY to do it and further won't pass any event to any app/socket/rfcomm/anything... E.g. under VOL UP button we have some well-known AT command, system can handle it, so try to do so, even when we already have volume set to max. Any app won't be noticed that this happened...

btw. I don't think this logcat line posted in question is strictly relevant to button press (but may be indirectly), but you have `bt-rfcomm` keyword in there, so you may try to establish some [RFCOMM connection with Bluetooth device](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), maybe you will get some luck on this topic... (personally I gave up...)